# Show hidden form when logged as admin(javascript,php)

Tags: javascript, php

I have created simple login button,which can only admin log in (only 1 password works).After clicking on a button "LOG IN" it takes me to the new html file.There is a form in this new html file that is  hidden but I want it to be visible when i enter it with login.So I was thinking about document.getElementById("hidden_form").style.display = "block"; but that form is not in that HTML file so that cant work.

This is the javascript of the button (so when i click on it it opens a new html document)

```
<input type="password" id="password" /><br />
<input class="orangebutton" type="submit" value="Nastavi" 
onclick="if (document.getElementById('password').value == 'password')
 location.href='index.html'; else alert('Wrong password!');
" />
```

And this is the form that is hidden in index.html:

```
 <form class="echo" id="form" style="display:none">
```

So I want it to change from display:none to display:block when I get redirected to the new site.I havent really got any ideas so far, except this one:use javascript to check which was the previous page client went on, and if it was the page of the login then put display:block , but if it isnt then do display:none.
Im sure there is some much easier way, but cant think of any at the moment.

Comment: please give us more info (and optionally source code). Downvoted until more description is given.

Comment: Sorry for the short question.I have edited it now, so it should be kind of easier to see my problem

Comment: I suggest you don't use JS and/or CSS to hide things; JS can be disabled, plus HTML/CSS can always be viewed in the HTML source. What I suggest you do is to use PHP conditional statements which is server-side and not client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change something on a new/other page, you should do that in the other page. With javscript you cannot change something that isn't loaded yet.

Easiest way to do this with javascript would be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (location.search == "?show") {
    document.getElementById("hidden_form").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Note that this script should be executed after the `<form>` is added to the DOM. So preferably in some `document.ready` function or in a script block that is placed below the `<form>`.